# ScheduledTaskAgent and GeoCoordinateWatcher in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, backgroundworker

I have very controversial info about ScheduledTaskAgent and GeoCoordinateWatcher working together.

First thing i'd like to point out is that ScheduledTaskAgent does not run in every 30 min as described at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). I tried and it turned out that my task runs at every 10 - 20sec, depending how long does task itself takes time. How do you comment that?

Also [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that GeoCoordinateWatcher gets coordinates from cache when running in background and renews the data in 15 min. I have seen apps that track route and definitely not in every 15 min. What kind of a magic do they use then?

Have any of you had same questions? And where did you find the answers?

Comment: You should contact microsoft because some apps use Private API's to do that and other reserved things.